# Visiting Canada when in US on a B1 visa

Tags: usa, canada, indian-citizens

If I visit Canada over a weekend from US while in US on a B1 visa for work, what are the chances of complications during reentry to the US?

Is it as trivial as visiting a city in US, or is there a chance of having issues getting back into the US after visiting Canada (which would be kind of disastrous since I would have a lot of stuff in the hotel, and still have a few days of critical meetings to attend)

Comment: Is your US visa multiple entry ?

Comment: @Blackbird57 Yup, standard 10 year multiple entry B1/B2

Comment: There is always a chance you would have issues.  However, it is likely no greater than the chance you'd be denied entry in the first place.  As you have visited the US many times the chance is probably infinitesimal.

Comment: @DJClayworth Posted that as a separate question, my understanding is its not a good idea to club questions on the SE platform :)

Comment: @Blackbird57: Even if it weren't multiple entry, they can re-enter the US on automatic revalidation as long as their I-94 is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

One potential complication is that the US doesn't electronically track departures by land. So, if you drive to Canada and then take a flight from Canada back to India, the US will not know that you have departed and you might be considered to have overstayed. To avoid this, you can either return to the US to take your flight home, or if you *plan* to fly home from Canada, inform the CBP officer of this *when you first arrive in the US* and request a paper I-94W form; you turn this in to the CBSA officer at the Canada border entry.

You shouldn't have an issue reentering the US from Canada, as you have a multiple entry B-1 visa, which permits business and transit entries.

Comment: Thanks..  and and if I go to as well as come back from Canada by land, the missing departure wont be a problem (since it would appear that I'm entering the country without exiting it :/)

Comment: No that won't be a problem. Many people do this all the time.